# Connect-Azure AD in PowerShell Script called from C# fails in a specific way THE FIRST TIME, then works?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

Here's the gist of my issue.  I have a C# program that is calling several PowerShell cmdlets.

All the calls work, except when I get to "Connect-AzureAD -TenantId XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

But the way it "fails" is odd.  It only lets me enter my Microsoft Account, but not the password.  IF I RUN IT AGAIN, I can log in correctly and it works.

I thought I was hitting a timeout of some kind, but each call bellow results in a Null Reference Exception.  You can see my comments of frustration.

```
 // All of these are set to null...so what gives?
 // all generate NRE's
 //Debug.Print("MaxIdle Timeout is |{0}|", runspace.ConnectionInfo.MaxIdleTimeout.ToString());
 //Debug.Print("Current Idle Timeout is |{0}|", runspace.ConnectionInfo.IdleTimeout.ToString());
 //Debug.Print("Operation Timeout is |{0}|", runspace.ConnectionInfo.OperationTimeout.ToString());
```

Thoughts, ideas, comments?

I can post more of the code, if needed, but everything else works all the time.

Per a comment, I added a CR, but it appeared to do nothing (I will try a CR+LF, because I have no idea what's actually broken here, so there's no harm in trying).

So...after the PowerShell invoke call, I collect the results as follows:

```
      foreach (PSObject outputObject in results)
```

and my results collection has these four errors in it: 
{One or more errors occurred.:  The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.} 
{One or more errors occurred.} 
{ The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.} 
{One or more errors occurred.:  The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.}

### It's telling me what I already know (that auth didn't work), but I'm still clueless as to what the actual issue is.

Adding some more detail

So...I've tried a few things.  I added my Microsoft account to the connect.  The result was even more odd -- a long delay, no password screen, and failure to log in.

Then I pivoted to setting up an application principal as detailed here:  "Using a Service Principal to connect to a directory in PowerShell" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0

I got it all set up and verified in PowerShell that I can connect, then I placed the exact same (I copied and pasted it) Connect-AzureAD with the tenant, application ID, and certificate thumbprint that I used in PowerShell.  It failed with these "new" errors -- still four somehow:
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'login.microsoftonline.com'
One or more errors occurred.

Tomorrow, I'll fire up Wireshark.  I'm getting the feeling that these errors are all misleading, although the fact that it works on the second try is just mind boggling.

Comment: You may need a return or using the wrong type of return (CR or CRLF)

Comment: I tried a CR and it failed again, but I did get some useful information from the code, which I probably should have included in my original post.  The code looks like this: "          foreach (PSObject outputObject in results)" and my results collection has these errors in it:

Comment: What errors?  When you run manually do you enter one CR for Account and one CR for password?  The doing same in script.

Comment: I added those details above.  Ran out of space in my reply...